# control flow (while): I need to apear in my virtual device

Tags: performance, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, gradle-kotlin-dsl

i'm to learning programing in kotlin and i practicing with the control flow (wile), the problem is that i want to appear ten number in my virtual device and just appear one.

This is the my code:

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    button.setOnClickListener {

        var num = ingrese_valor.text.toString().toInt()


        while (num < 10) {

            num++

            tv_resultad.text = ("" + num)

        }

    }

}
```

}

Exanple :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mxxW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the previous text from the `TextView` and append it with new number.

replace `tv_resultad.text = ("" + num)` with this

```
tv_resultad.text = tv_resultad.text.toString().plus(num)
```

Comment: no problem. check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers